# SQLAlchemy Filter Query over Datetime timezone

Tags: python, sql, database, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter data with timezone. But the query is filtering data based on the datetime object values.

My Entire Code is :

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import datetime
import pytz

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydatabase121.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

# Creating table over Base
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Creating Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

#Inserting Data with Timezone in the table

# Create a new record with a DateTime value of January 1st, 2024 at 10:00 AM in the US/Eastern timezone
created_at = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))
record = MyTable(created_at=created_at)
session.add(record)
session.commit()
# Create a new record with a DateTime value of January 1st, 2024 at 11:00 AM in the UTC timezone
created_at = pytz.timezone('UTC').localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 11, 0))
record = MyTable(created_at=created_at)
session.add(record)
session.commit()
# Create a new record with a DateTime value of January 1st, 2024 at 12:00 AM in the US/Eastern timezone
created_at = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 12, 0))
record = MyTable(created_at=created_at)
session.add(record)
session.commit()


#Filtering the data based on  DateTime values in a specific timezone. 

# Query for all records in the table that have a DateTime value of January 1st, 2024 at 10:00 AM in the US/Eastern timezone
records = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.created_at == pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))).all()

# Print the records
print("\nPrinting Record : \n")
for record in records:
    print(record.id, record.created_at)




# Convert a DateTime value that represents first data in record in the US/Eastern timezone to the UTC timezone
def convert_datetime_timezone(dt, tz1, tz2):
    tz1 = pytz.timezone(tz1)
    tz2 = pytz.timezone(tz2)
    dt = dt.astimezone(tz1)
    dt = tz2.normalize(dt.astimezone(tz2))
    dt = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return dt

converted = convert_datetime_timezone(records[0].created_at, 'US/Eastern', 'UTC')
converted2 = convert_datetime_timezone(records[0].created_at, 'US/Eastern', 'Asia/Kolkata')

# Print the converted DateTime value
print("\nDatetime Converted in UTC Timezone: \n")
print(converted)
print("\nDatetime Converted in Indian Timezone: \n")
print(converted2)
```

The query should filter only those data that has datetimevalues equals to what is in the query and also timezone mentioned.
But Output:
[image: Output]

THe code is not filtering data with timezone it is filtering data based on the datetime object values.

I want to improve the filter function so that different it can filter data with timezone.

Above is the screenshot that is inserting 5 data and if we am query data base on UTC,US/Eastern  than the record which we are getting can not be 3,4,5.

```
   records = session.query(MyTable).filter(
           MyTable.created_at == pytz.timezone(
           'US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 1, 11, 0))
       ).all()

     # Print the records
      print("\nPrinting Record : \n")
      for record in records:
        print(record.id, record.created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: Since SQLite does not support timezone operations we will try something else, we will do the filtering in python

```
# Specify the timezone you want to filter records by
target_timezone = 'US/Eastern'

# Specify the datetime you want to filter records by (already localized to the target timezone)
target_datetime = pytz.timezone(target_timezone).localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))

# Retrieve all records from the table
all_records = session.query(MyTable).all()

# Filter the records by checking if the created_at datetime in the target timezone is equal to the target datetime
filtered_records = [
    record for record in all_records
    if record.created_at.astimezone(pytz.timezone(target_timezone)) == target_datetime
]

# Print the filtered records
print("\nPrinting Record : \n")
for record in filtered_records:
    print(record.id, record.created_at)
```

Adjust the `filter` function to take the `timezone` into account, just convert the `datetime` values in the database to the target timezone before comparing them.

So first you gonna have to import `func`

```
from sqlalchemy import func
```

then modify your code like this

```
# Specify the timezone you want to filter records by
target_timezone = 'US/Eastern'

# Specify the datetime you want to filter records by (already localized to the target timezone)
target_datetime = pytz.timezone(target_timezone).localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))

# Query for all records in the table that have a DateTime value equal to the target datetime in the target timezone
records = session.query(MyTable).filter(
    func.timezone(target_timezone, MyTable.created_at) == target_datetime
).all()
```

edit: if you have this error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: timezone` it is because `timezone` is not supported by `SQLite`, use `strftime` instead like this:

```
# Specify the timezone you want to filter records by
target_timezone = 'US/Eastern'

# Specify the datetime you want to filter records by (already localized to the target timezone)
target_datetime = pytz.timezone(target_timezone).localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))

# Query for all records in the table that have a DateTime value equal to the target datetime in the target timezone
records = session.query(MyTable).filter(
    func.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', 'localtime', MyTable.created_at) == target_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
).all()
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it gives error: 
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: timezone

Comment: The query is not able to find any record. Records is empty even if it exists in table.

Comment: 2023-04-20 14:39:00,130 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT my_table.id AS my_table_id, my_table.created_at AS my_table_created_at 
FROM my_table 
WHERE strftime(?, ?, my_table.created_at) = ?
2023-04-20 14:39:00,130 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00034s] ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', 'localtime', '2025-01-01 10:00:00.000000')

Comment: I modified my answer

Comment: The filtered records still remains empty. When I print datetime values stored in table, it does not contain timezone info. strftime("%Z") return None.

Comment: I have a similar problem with mssql, (using pyodbc) and using almost exactly the same query as above, I get the error "'timezone' is not a recognized built-in function name."